# Foreach doubling data from query

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am creating a page in order: Date (Panel 1 (News 1 News 2)). The data work individually, but when together two stories within a panel they duplicate. Like This:

[image: Data]

And when the data is alone in the panel, it does not duplicate:

[image: Data]

Foreach doubling data:

```
<?php foreach ($dados_programacao_painel as $key => $programacao_painel) { ?>
<?php
$sql_conteudo = "SELECT programacao.*, programacao_traducao.* FROM programacao JOIN programacao_traducao on (programacao.programacao_id = programacao_traducao.programacao_id)WHERE programacao_traducao.idioma_id = :idioma_id AND programacao.painel_id = '".$programacao_painel['painel_id']."' AND programacao.ativo = 1";
$dados_bind_conteudo = array('idioma_id'=>$idioma_id_atual);
$dados_programacao_conteudo = $db->query($sql_conteudo, $dados_bind_conteudo);

...

<?php } ?>
```

I want to bring the news grouped by panel. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: You should narrow down your code you posted to the `foreach` that is causing the error, not all of them!

Comment: Done. That's the foreach doubling the data.

Comment: What does the data look like when you fetch it?

Comment: This: "SELECT programacao . * , programacao_traducao . * FROM programacao JOIN programacao_traducao ON ( programacao.programacao_id = programacao_traducao.programacao_id ) WHERE programacao_traducao.idioma_id =2 AND programacao.dia =  '2015-01-22' AND programacao.ativo =1 ORDER BY programacao.painel_id" PS: In phpMyAdmin SQL works, but in foreach doubles.

Comment: Solved! I missed only one GROUP BY to join the panels. Thank you for those who tried to help me.

Comment: You can also try `LEFT JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`